# AndroidStudio 3.6.3 does not generate all BR constants

Tags: java, android, android-studio, data-binding

I've been playing with bindings (in actions and fragments) until I managed to get it (partially) working. I am binding six variables (and they are properly shown in the application), but generated BR file has only three definitions (and only one of them corresponds to one of my variables)

My main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The layout of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="data"
            type="Data" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".FragmentFloor0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_floor0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:text="@string/label_floor0"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeRegular"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageGroundFloor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/label_floor0"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ground_floor_v2"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:contentDescription="@string/blueprint_0th_floor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/liviTempStr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.fl0_liviTempStr}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeRegular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.788"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/liviTempTel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.fl0_liviTempTel}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeRegular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kitcTempSin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.fl0_kitcTempSin}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeRegular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.32"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bathTempSin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.fl0_bathTempSin}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeRegular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hallTempSin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.fl0_hallTempEx1}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeRegular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.62"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hallTempEx1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.fl0_hallTempEx1}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeRegular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            android:rotation="90"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.65"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hallHummEx1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.fl0_hallHummEx1}"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeRegular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.65"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageGroundFloor"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_floor0_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:text="@string/button_next"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Data binding class:

```
import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable;
import androidx.databinding.Bindable;

public class HomematicData extends BaseObservable  {
    private float fl0_liviTempStr;
    private float fl0_liviTempTel;
    private float fl0_kitcTempSin;
    private float fl0_bathTempSin;
    private float fl0_hallTempEx1;
    private float fl0_hallHummEx1;

    @Bindable
    public float getFl0_liviTempStr() { return fl0_liviTempStr; }
    public float getFl0_liviTempTel() { return fl0_liviTempTel; }
    public float getFl0_kitcTempSin() { return fl0_kitcTempSin; }
    public float getFl0_bathTempSin() { return fl0_bathTempSin; }
    public float getFl0_hallTempEx1() { return fl0_hallTempEx1; }
    public float getFl0_hallHummEx1() { return fl0_hallHummEx1; }
    public void setFl0_liviTempTel(float fl0_liviTempTel) { this.fl0_liviTempTel = fl0_liviTempTel; /* notifyPropertyChanged(BR.fl0_liviTempTel); */ }
    public void setFl0_liviTempStr(float fl0_liviTempStr) { this.fl0_liviTempStr = fl0_liviTempStr; /* notifyPropertyChanged(BR.fl0_liviTempStr); */ }
    public void setFl0_kitcTempSin(float fl0_kitcTempSin) { this.fl0_kitcTempSin = fl0_kitcTempSin; /* notifyPropertyChanged(BR.fl0_kitcTempSin); */ }
    public void setFl0_bathTempSin(float fl0_bathTempSin) { this.fl0_bathTempSin = fl0_bathTempSin; /* notifyPropertyChanged(BR.fl0_ballTempSin); */ }
    public void setFl0_hallTempEx1(float fl0_hallTempEx1) { this.fl0_hallTempEx1 = fl0_hallTempEx1; /* notifyPropertyChanged(BR.fl0_hallTempEx1); */ }
    public void setFl0_hallHummEx1(float fl0_hallHummEx1) { this.fl0_hallHummEx1 = fl0_hallHummEx1; /* notifyPropertyChanged(BR.fl0_hallTempEx1); */ }
```

Main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment Activity:

```
public class FragmentFloor0 extends Fragment {
    private FragmentFloor0Binding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_floor0, container, false);

        View rootView = binding.getRoot();
        HomematicData hd = new HomematicData();

        hd.setFl0_liviTempStr(1.0f);
        hd.setFl0_liviTempTel(2.0f);
        hd.setFl0_bathTempSin(3.0f);
        hd.setFl0_kitcTempSin(4.0f);
        hd.setFl0_hallTempEx1(5.0f);
        hd.setFl0_hallHummEx1(6.0f);
        binding.setData(hd);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        view.findViewById(R.id.button_floor0_next).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FragmentFloor0.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FragmentFloor0_to_FragmentFloor1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Binding Adaptor:

```
public class BindingUtils {

    @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    public static void setFloat(TextView view, float value) {
        if (Float.isNaN(value)) view.setText("");
        else view.setText(String.format("%.1f", value));
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    public static float getFloat(TextView view) {
        String num = view.getText().toString();
        if(num.isEmpty()) return 0.0F;
        try {
            return Float.parseFloat(num);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 0.0F;
        }
    }
```

and generated BR:

```
package androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters;

public class BR {
  public static final int _all = 0;

  public static final int data = 1;

  public static final int fl0_liviTempStr = 2;
}
```

where are all other constants?!

I have clean-build and rebuild project, as well as invalidated the cache and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that `@Bindable` needs to be added before every getter